# How to avoid error in default condition in the switch statement in the new way Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

How do I avoid an error in switch statement in "default"?This switch case is wiritten according to  the new standrads.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SwitchCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Choose option: ");
        char userChoice = scan.next().charAt(0);
        switch (userChoice) {
            case '1' -> System.out.println("1 funkcja");
            case '2' -> System.out.println("2 funkcja");
            default ->
                if((!Character.isDigit(userChoice))||(userChoice>3)){     #this part throws an error below:
                  System.out.println("Input error");
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

An error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error, insert "ThrowExpression ;" to complete SwitchLabeledThrowStatement
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete SwitchBlock
    Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

    at SwitchCase.main(SwitchCase.java:11)
```

Comment: `default -> {  /* if statement */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Check this:
You need to use : for switch cases.
We are comparing userChoice which is char to 3(an int).

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Choose option: ");
    char userChoice = scan.next().charAt(0);
    switch (userChoice) {
        case '1': System.out.println("1 funkcja");
        case '2': System.out.println("2 funkcja");
        default:
            if(!Character.isDigit(userChoice)||(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(userChoice))>3)){     //#this part throws an error below:
              System.out.println(userChoice + " Input error");
        }
    }
    scan.close();
       
   }
```